# bottomCalc sum value not in alignment with header

Tags: tabulator

## Issue description

I have field `Fat` with a `bottomCalc`:

```
{ title: "Fat", field: "Fat", bottomCalc: "sum" },
```

Note that the sum value doesn't align with the header, `Fat`:

[image]

## Question

Is there something I can do to resolve this? Or is it possibly a bug?

## Runnable snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Index - NutritionTrackerRazorPages</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">NutritionTracker</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/FoodCategories">Food Categories</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/SimpleFoods">Simple Foods</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/ComplexFoods">Complex Foods</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/ComplexFoodComponents/IndexGrouped">Complex Food Components</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/FoodRecords">Food Records</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/FoodRecords/IndexGrouped">Food Records Grouped</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/FoodRecords/IndexTabulator">Food Records Tabulator</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        

<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
<a href="/FoodRecords/Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<div id="data-table"></div>

<script>

//var table_data = [

//    { id: 1, name: "Oli Bob", age: "12", col: "red", dob: "" },
//    { id: 2, name: "Mary May", age: "1", col: "blue", dob: "14/05/1982" },
//    { id: 3, name: "Christine Lobowski", age: "42", col: "green", dob: "22/05/1982" },
//    { id: 4, name: "Brendon Philips", age: "125", col: "orange", dob: "01/08/1980" },
//    { id: 5, name: "Margret Marmajuke", age: "16", col: "yellow", dob: "31/01/1999" }
    
//];

var table_data = [


            { 
                id: 3, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "12:00 PM",
                food: "Avocado (g)",
                amount: "50",
                
                Calories          : "84",
                Fat               : "7.70",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "4.30",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "1.00",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 4, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "12:00 PM",
                food: "Basmati Rice (g)",
                amount: "300",
                
                Calories          : "1067",
                Fat               : "3.33",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "240",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "20",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 5, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "12:00 PM",
                food: "Ground Beef 80/20 (g)",
                amount: "200",
                
                Calories          : "508",
                Fat               : "32",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "0",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "51",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 1, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "6:00 PM",
                food: "Onion (g)",
                amount: "150",
                
                Calories          : "60",
                Fat               : "0.15",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "14",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "1.65",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 2, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "6:00 PM",
                food: "Lentils (g)",
                amount: "250",
                
                Calories          : "714",
                Fat               : "3.57",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "164",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "57",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 6, 
                date: "1/1/2021",
                time: "6:00 PM",
                food: "Basmati Rice (g)",
                amount: "350",
                
                Calories          : "1244",
                Fat               : "3.89",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "280",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "23",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },

{ 
                id: 14, 
                date: "1/3/2021",
                time: "12:00 PM",
                food: "Salmon (g)",
                amount: "150",
                
                Calories          : "230",
                Fat               : "11",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "0",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "33",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 17, 
                date: "1/3/2021",
                time: "12:00 PM",
                food: "LimaYamOnion",
                amount: "300",
                
                Calories          : "13",
                Fat               : "0.03",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "3.07",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "0.36",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            { 
                id: 18, 
                date: "1/3/2021",
                time: "6:00 PM",
                food: "LimaYamOnion",
                amount: "500",
                
                Calories          : "22",
                Fat               : "0.06",
                MonounsaturatedFat: "0",
                PolyunsaturatedFat: "0",
                Omega3            : "0",
                Omega6            : "0",
                SaturatedFat      : "0",
                TransFat          : "0",
                Cholesterol       : "0",
                Carbohydrates     : "5.12",
                Fiber             : "0",
                SolubleFiber      : "0",
                InsolubleFiber    : "0",
                Starch            : "0",
                Sugars            : "0",
                AddedSugars       : "0",
                Protein           : "0.61",
                VitaminB1         : "0",
                VitaminB2         : "0",
                VitaminB3         : "0",
                VitaminB5         : "0",
                VitaminB6         : "0",
                VitaminB12        : "0",
                Folate            : "0",
                VitaminA          : "0",
                VitaminC          : "0",
                VitaminD          : "0",
                VitaminE          : "0",
                VitaminK          : "0",
                Calcium           : "0",
                Copper            : "0",
                Iron              : "0",
                Magnesium         : "0",
                Manganese         : "0",
                Phosphorus        : "0",
                Potassium         : "0",
                Selenium          : "0",
                Sodium            : "0",
                Zinc              : "0",
            },
        
            ];

var table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {

    height: 500,
    //height: "auto",

    //maxHeight:"100%",

    data: table_data,
    //layout: "fitColumns",

    //headerHozAlign:"center",

    groupBy: ["date", "time"],

    //responsiveLayout: "hide",

    //columnCalcs: "group",
    //columnCalcs: "both",

    groupHeader: function (value, count, data, group) {
        return value;
    },

    groupToggleElement: "header",

    columns: [
        //{ title: "Date", field: "date" },
        //{ title: "Time", field: "time" },
        //{ title: "Food", field: "food" },
        { title: "Food", field: "food", frozen:true },
        { title: "Amt", field: "amount" },

        //{ title: "Cals", field: "calories" },

        { title: "Cals",           field: "Calories" },

        {
            title: "Lipids",
            columns: [
                { title: "Fat", field: "Fat", bottomCalc: "sum" },
                //{ title: "Fat", field: "Fat" },
                { title: "Mono", field: "MonounsaturatedFat" },
                { title: "Poly", field: "PolyunsaturatedFat" },
                { title: "Om3", field: "Omega3" },
                { title: "Om6", field: "Omega6" },
                { title: "Sat", field: "SaturatedFat" },
                { title: "Trans", field: "TransFat" },
                { title: "Chol", field: "Cholesterol" },
            ]
        },

        {
            title: "Carbohydrates",
            columns: [
                { title: "Carbs", field: "Carbohydrates" },
                { title: "Fiber", field: "Fiber" },
                { title: "Sol", field: "SolubleFiber" },
                { title: "Ins", field: "InsolubleFiber" },
                { title: "Starch", field: "Starch" },
                { title: "Sug", field: "Sugars" },
                { title: "Add", field: "AddedSugars" },
            ]
        },

        { title: "Pro", field: "Protein" },

        {
            title: "Vitamins",
            columns: [
                { title: "B1", field: "VitaminB1" },
                { title: "B2", field: "VitaminB2" },
                { title: "B3", field: "VitaminB3" },
                { title: "B5", field: "VitaminB5" },
                { title: "B6", field: "VitaminB6" },
                { title: "B12", field: "VitaminB12" },
                { title: "Fol", field: "Folate" },
                { title: "A", field: "VitaminA" },
                { title: "C", field: "VitaminC" },
                { title: "D", field: "VitaminD" },
                { title: "E", field: "VitaminE" },
                { title: "K", field: "VitaminK" },
            ]
        },

        {
            title: "Minerals",
            columns: [
                { title: "Calc", field: "Calcium" },
                { title: "Cop", field: "Copper" },
                { title: "Iron", field: "Iron" },
                { title: "Mag", field: "Magnesium" },
                { title: "Mang", field: "Manganese" },
                { title: "Phos", field: "Phosphorus" },
                { title: "Pot", field: "Potassium" },
                { title: "Sel", field: "Selenium" },
                { title: "Sod", field: "Sodium" },
                { title: "Zin", field: "Zinc" }
            ]
        }
    ],

    //rowClick: function (e, row) {
    //    alert("Row " + row.getData().id + " Clicked!!!!");
    //},
});

</script>

    </main>
</div>

<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2021 - NutritionTrackerRazorPages - <a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>


<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not able to repoduce your problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7t4dhqxp/) If you're able to modify to reproduce, it would help. or its a browser version issue ? What browser/OS combo are you using (I tested on Chrome/Rasbian and Firefox/Windows8)

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: Michael, in your jsfiddle, when I resize the 'alpha' column, the misalignment occurs:
 https://i.imgur.com/iXE9k5f.png

What happens when you resize the 'alpha' column?

Comment: The bottomCalc row doesnt move appropriately. That is definitely a bug. You should file it over on gitHub under Issues (https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues) - Check that it's not already there though first

Comment: Yup, I figured so. I added a bug report yesterday. :-) https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3330 Thank you for helping to confirm it!

Comment: seems tied to the rowGroup code. Remove the group parameter from the fiddle, and it resizes OK

Comment: This was fixed in a later update of Tabulator